# MySQL Hierarchy based on email

Tags: mysql, recursion, tree, hierarchy

I have an `Employees` database with `MySQL v5.6` as following:

```
| emp_name | emp_email | direct_manager_email |
|    x     |  x@co.com |      y@co.com        |
|    z     |  z@co.com |      x@co.com        |
|    y     |  y@co.com |      m@co.com        |
```

For example: I want to run a query to get all childs of `y@co.com`, so I get:

```
| emp_name | emp_email | direct_manager_email |
|    x     |  x@co.com |      y@co.com        |
|    z     |  z@co.com |      x@co.com        |
```

How can I get that?

This question is not a duplicate, the other one is depending on integer values not strings.

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: @RaymondNijland, v5.6

Comment: All possible MySQL 5.6 recursive methods are in that duplication link.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, they’re all based on levels, not emails. I already reviewed them before posting my question.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, This question is not a duplicate, the other one is depending on integer values not strings.

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that in the question..If you had reviewex or tryed those methods

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I just did.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, still duplicate?!

Comment: Well i don't have reopen rights.. "still duplicate?" Yes there are methods in that duplication link which can and will work with strings.. The function or (recursive) stored procedure  is the best option.